# How the condition to check whether the link's size in a symbolic link file is too big, works in this code?

Tags: c, linux, gnu, symlink

Here is a piece of code from the lib/xreadlink.c file in GNU Coreutils..

```
  /* Call readlink to get the symbolic link value of FILENAME.
   +   SIZE is a hint as to how long the link is expected to be;
   +   typically it is taken from st_size.  It need not be correct.
       Return a pointer to that NUL-terminated string in malloc'd storage.
       If readlink fails, return NULL (caller may use errno to diagnose).
       If malloc fails, or if the link value is longer than SSIZE_MAX :-),
       give a diagnostic and exit.  */

 char * xreadlink (char const *filename)
 {
    /* The initial buffer size for the link value.  A power of 2
       detects arithmetic overflow earlier, but is not required.  */
    size_t buf_size = 128;

    while (1)
    {
      char* buffer = xmalloc(buf_size);
      ssize_t link_length = readlink(filename, buffer, buf_size);
      if(link_length < 0)
      {
         /*handle failure of system call*/
      }

      if((size_t) link_length < buf_size)
      {
           buffer[link_length] = 0;
           return buffer;
      }

      /*size not sufficient, allocate more*/
      free (buffer);
      buf_size *= 2;
      /*Check whether increase is possible*/
      if (SSIZE_MAX < buf_size || (SIZE_MAX / 2 < SSIZE_MAX && buf_size == 0))
          xalloc_die ();
   }
}
```

The code is understandable except I could not understand how the check for whether the link's size is too big works, that is the line:

```
      if (SSIZE_MAX < buf_size || (SIZE_MAX / 2 < SSIZE_MAX && buf_size == 0))
```

Further, how can

```
     (SIZE_MAX / 2 < SSIZE_MAX)
```

condition be true on any system???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SSIZE_MAX` is the maximum value of the signed variety of `size_t`.  For instance if `size_t` is only 16 bits (very unlikely these days), `SIZE_MAX` is 65535 while `ssize_max` is 32767.  More likely it is 32 bits (giving 4294967295 and 2147483647 respectively), or even 64 bits (giving numbers too big to type here :-) ).

The basic problem to solve here is that `readlink` returns a signed value even though `SIZE_MAX` is an unsigned one ... so once `buf_size` exceeds `SSIZE_MAX`, it's impossible to read the link, as the large positive value will result in a negative return value.

As for the "furthermore" part: it quite likely can't, i.e., you're right.  At least on any sane system, anyway.  (It is theoretically possible to have, e.g., a 32-bit `SIZE_MAX` but a 33-bit signed integer so that SSIZE_MAX is also 4294967295.  Presumably this code is written to guard against theoretically-possible, but never-actually-seen, systems.)